# How would one mock an axios({method: "GET", url:"/something"}) request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, axios

```js
axios({method: "GET", url:"/something"})
```

How can I mock this type of Axios request? I am using jest for testing in a react-native project (without expo)

Comment: [The same way you would mock anything else](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions).

Answer (score 2):

```
import axios from 'axios';
 
jest.mock('axios');
 
describe('fetchData', () => {
  it('fetches successfully data from an API', async () => {
    const data = {
      data: {
      },
    };
 
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(data));
  });
```